# Javascript literal loses its variables when called with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, variables, settimeout

I have this piece of code, and it doesn't work as I expect (it's demo code, distilled from a larger program):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var test = {
    variable: true,
    go: function() {
        alert(this.variable);
    }
};

function s() {
    test.go();
    setTimeout(test.go, 500);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="s();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the Go button, both in IE and FF (the only browsers I care about atm), the first alert box shows "true", the second one "undefined".

My questions are why, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**`setTimeout`** will execute the passed function in the context of the window, so 'this' refers to the window. Try this instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    test.go();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 4):

change the line

```
setTimeout(test.go, 500);
```

with

```
setTimeout(function(){test.go()}, 500);
```

and your script shoud work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like "this" points to something else when you call "go" from the timeout. it probably points to window.

try something like this

```
var fn = function(){
    test.go.apply(test, []);
}
setTimetout(fn, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was first, but the others are shorter, so I accepted one of them.